# moderncv classic header

Tags: header-footer, moderncv

I was trying to add an additional header for every new page of my CV (2nd page and onward), but unfortunately everything I tried ended in a failure.

I've tried editing "moderncvstyleclassic.sty" and adding a new command similar to \makecvtitle command. I'm new to latex, so probably I just messed code somewhere.

```
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

(...) %personal info

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title, so for the 1st page I don't need a new header

(...) %some info here 

\clearpage
\header %%% I need a header here

\end{document}
```

I was looking to add black/gray color header with fonts 18/16 like:

```
John Doe                                                         Curriculum Vitae
```

Comment: You should provide us with something to work with, just so it's easier to get started. Do so by constructing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: Did you mean adding something like this?

Comment: `moderncv` uses `fancyhdr` to setup headers and footers, are you trying to accomplish something that can be done with `fancyhdr`? If so you can use the `fancyhdr` macros directly in you document to setup the header/footer styles

Comment: Ok now I'm confused, I've tried using `\chead` (since I used `\cfoot` already)  but it gave me an error then and that's why I was looking for another solution with headers, now I've found out about `\lhead`, `\rhead` (those are which I needed with a small editing for fonts and color), so I've tried using `\chead` again and now it works ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bordaigorl Thx for hinting me in the right direction.

The problem was so simple that it's kinda stupid. So, sorry for taking your time.

I was looking for something like this:

```
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

(...) %personal info

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title, so for the 1st page I don't need a new header

(...) %some info here 

\clearpage
\lhead{\fontsize{20}{22}\mdseries\upshape{John Doe}}
\rhead{\Large\mdseries\slshape{\color{gray}{Curriculum Vitae}}}

(...) % more info

\end{document}
```